# Mongoose - Push value to array which is nested in object which is nested in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

unfortunately I can only find very specific questions on stackoverflow and no exact details in the documentation, so here is a more general example that may help others too.

I just want to add a value to the array (arr) in the object with the "title: 'title3".

```
{
_id: <id>,
prop1: val1,
prop2: val2,
prop3: [
    {
        title: 'title1',
        arr: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
    },
    {
        title: 'title2',
        arr: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
    },
    {
        title: 'title3',
        arr: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], //only update this array
    }
]
}
```

My current approach looks something like this:

```
SomeModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id, "prop3.title": "title3" },
    {$push: { "prop3.$[].arr": someDoc._id.toString() }}, 
    (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error updating doc: ', err);
            resolve(false);
        } else {
            resolve(doc);
        }
    }
);
```

However, the problem here is that a value is added not only in the array of the object with the title "title3", but everywhere.

How can I add a value exclusively to the array in the object with the title value "title3"?
I would also be very grateful for links to documentation explaining this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positional `$` operator in this way to do it in a single operation:

Using [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) you tell mongo "update the object found in the find stage". In this case "update the object where `prop3.title` is `title3`".

Note that you are using [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) instead of positional operator.

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1,
  "prop3.title": "title3"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "prop3.$.arr": "val4"
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AR9aq3ZPJ-F)

Comment: Thank you very much mate, that was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution which may or may not make sense in your full context.

You would have much more luck using the `mongoose` [Document.save()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating-using-save) method. Once you have a local copy of the document, you can simply push to the array:

```js
const doc = await SomeModel.findOne({
    _id: id, 
    "prop3.title": "title3" 
});

doc.prop3[3].arr.push(item);
await doc.save();
```